# CentOS 8 Pane is dead VMware Workstation 15.5

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-player, centos8

I am using VMware Workstation 15.5 and trying to install CentOS 8. When I boot and it starts the installer it gives me a message on the
bottom "Pane is dead". I tried to set "install operating system later", picked CentOS 7, selected ISO as the CD ROM device and attempted the install.
Unfortunately VMware does not pick up the boot device as ISO and goes right to DHCP boot. So I tried a CentOS 7 ISO, same thing. I just upgraded VMware Workstation from 15.0 to 15.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution to this problem.

1. You need to download your CentOS 8 iso.
2. Open VMware and create a virtual machine like normal, editing as you want, and don't worry if VMware detects it as CentOS 5 or
   earlier, just keep ongoing.
3. Launch your VM and wait, if it shows you the "Pane is dead" just turn off the virtual machine.
4. Open de settings of your VM and just remove the disk "Using the autoinst.iso"
5. Open again your virtual machine and the problem probably will be fixed.

Comment: Worked for me. I went into the settings for the virtual machine and went to the first virtual CD/DVD drive, saw it had "autoinst.iso" mounted, so I removed that virtual cd drive from the virtual machine.  I'm guessing VMware tried to automate the install (with its "easy install") but incorrectly identified it as CentOS 5 so it's using an incompatible install script, so we just have to disable that script and go through the install steps manually.